# Installing uBlock using terminal

Tags: command-line

I've been trying to install uBlock using the command line with

```
sudo apt-get install -y ublock-origin-doc
```

but  I get “unable to locate package”. Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you get "sudo apt-get install -y ublock-origin-doc" from? Why don't you just install the extension via your browser?

Comment: You haven't said what release you are on.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=ublock-origin-doc  shows it's not available for all releases; next if you are on one of the releases that has it - have you enabled 'universe'?

Comment: from http://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/ublock-origin-doc

Comment: I have now installed the extension from the browser, thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you installed is the package containing documentation of the plugin
`ublock-origin-doc`
'doc' for documentation

To install the plugin, use this:

- For firefox
`sudo apt install webext-ublock-origin`

- For Chromium
`sudo apt install chromium-ublock-origin`

More information:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=ublock-origin&searchon=names

Comment: Still unable to find the package, but thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Ask the packaging system, and use the correct package name.

```
walt@fox:~(0)$ apt-cache search ublock
xul-ext-ublock-origin - general-purpose lightweight ads, malware, trackers blocker
walt@fox:~(0)$
```